# Laravel Spark login from python

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm using the new Laravel Spark (not classic) and I'd like to authenticate/login a user from python.

How can check if a user exists and login credentials?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you're integrating Python with your Laravel app?  Are you trying to add a Python based SSO?

Comment: I haven't done this yet, I'm looking for a way to do it.

Comment: Do you have another Python-based app that you want to integrate with a Laravel Spark app?  Are you trying to create an SSO?  Providing a few more details will help others answer your question.

Comment: Yes to the first question, don't know if that's considered an SSO though. I want to login the user from python using the same credentials as Laravel Spark/Jetstream.